# ¿Por qué no encuentra react-scripts?

Tags: reactjs, vscode, npm

```
$ npm start

> ivanbastarrica@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start

"react-scripts" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
```

al querer ejecutar npm start para ver mi proyecto en el navegador, se genera este problema y no lo ejecuta. Nose que hice.

Comment: `react-scripts` es algún ejecutable que tengas instalado? Parece que faltaría añadir algo al PATH para que lo encuentre...

Comment: deberias compartir tu archivo package.json (donde tenemos todas las dependencias del proyecto)para revistarlo tambien. Sino otra alternativa es instalar nuevamente el create-react-app, podes intentar reinstalar las dependencias, usando los comandos ```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app react-scripts
npm install -g create-react-app react-scripts
``` Ojala te sirva, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno en mi caso yo lo vi cuando no estaba en la carpeta correcta donde había colocado el proyecto, además que recién había clonado mi repositorio de git, lo que puedes hacer es volver a instalar con **npm install** en la carpeta correcta eso debería funcionar..  espero y le pueda ayudar a alguien :)

Answer (score -1):

Ejecuta:

```
npm i -g react-scripts
```

En el [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) en tu proyecto y después:

```
npm start
```

Debería solucionarlo.